# Relationship between Beta regression of Y on X and linear regression of X on Y. (where Y is a proportion)

Tags: regression, python, proportion, beta-regression

I am trying to model the relationship between school district funding and a district's poverty rate.

If I treat funding as the independent variable then the dependent is a proportion on [0,1]. This seems to be good for beta-regression. If I treat poverty rate as the independent variable then it seems good for simple linear regression.

So my question is - what are the differences between treating the proportion as independent with SLR or as the dependent with beta-regression?

SLR:

[image: This is the SLR regression line]

[image: This is logistic because I didn't see how to implement Beta in python...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is that in SLR you use the poverty rate which takes values in $[0,1]$ whereas in beta regression you use a transformation of poverty rate as the explanatory variable which takes values $(-\infty, \infty)$.

Let $Y$ be the poverty rate and $X$ be the funds per student.

In the **standard linear regression** you have fit the line $ X = b_0 + b_1 Y $ which can be rearranged to give
$$
Y = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 X
$$
where $\alpha_0 = -b_0/b_1$ and $\alpha_1 = 1/b_1$. This results in the straight line shown in your first graph.

For **beta regression** you fit the line
$$
f(Y) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X
$$
where $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. This ensures that $Y = f^{-1}(\beta_0 + \beta_1 X)$ gives a valid value for the proportion. This also explains why we see some non-linearity in the fitted line on your second plot.

Comment: Besides the link function $f$, also different is: 1. the error distribution (normal vs beta distributed) 2. the direction of regression attenuation (the bias in the curve line to the mean of $X$ vs the mean of $Y$) 3. the interpretation of the line (a predictor of $E(X|Y)$ versus a predictor of $E(Y|X)$). I would say that this attenuation is effectively/practically the main difference because linear regression of Y on X and linear regression of X on Y give a similar picture.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you made this was very clear!! And @Martijn, thank you!. So I guess I will just go with simple linear regression for the easy to interpret coefficients and its assumptions of normal error and linear relationship seem (sort of) satisfied.